# How to pass awk as an argument of another function

Tags: bash, awk

`levenshtein` is a function that gets two argument, and computes distance between them: I want to remove the first item of both argument using `awk` then give them to the `levenshtien` function, but it did not work:

```
levenshtein  awk '{$1=""; print}' text1  awk '{$1=""; print}' text2
```

BTW I could not solve my problem trough this link
[Bash: pass a function as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672289/bash-pass-a-function-as-parameter)

I am not interested with the following!

```
awk '{$1=""; print}' text1 > txt1
awk '{$1=""; print}' text2 > txt2
levenshtein txt1 txt2
```

Comment: You don't show any input so I could be wrong but I suspect you could use `awk '{print $2}' text1 text2` instead of any variant ot `awk '{$1=""; print}' text1  awk '{$1=""; print}' text2`. If you [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output we could help you more.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard output of a command as an argument for another using `$()` in bash. This is called [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

```
levenshtein $(awk '{$1=""; print}' text1) $(awk '{$1=""; print}' text2)
```

The difference between this and process substitution (in Dimitri's answer) is that you would use `$()` if your prorgam does not expect a file but text. If the program expects a file path then you are good to go with `<()`. Example:

```
cat <(echo hello)
```

If you want a single `awk` output to generate multiple arguments, you will need to go with `xargs`.

```
awk '{$1=""; print}' text1 text2 | xargs -n2 levenshtein
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a shell feature that is called [Process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) whereby the output of a process is used as an argument to a shell script or a shell function.

Vinicius Placco in the comments has shown how this could work in your case

```
 levenshtein <(awk '{$1=""; print}' text1) <(awk '{$1=""; print}' text2)
```

Note that this works only on systems that have Named Pipes or a similar mechnanism, that includes all Linux systems.

### Some details

This mechanism works as follows. A special file is created by the system that accumulates the output of a command `command` inside the `<( command )` argument. The name of this file is given as a positional argument to `levenshtein` script.

Another post suggested using [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) `$( command )` where the entire output of the command `command` is used to build the argument list for `levenshtein`.

For instance if the file `text1.txt` contains the lines

```
1 love
2 love
3 love 
...
```

then `levenshtein <( awk '{print $1} text1' )` would create a special file `/dev/fd/nn` and call `

```
levenshtein /dev/fd/nn
```

The contents of the file would be the output of `awk '{print $1}' text1`.

With command substitution `levenshtein $( awk '{print $1}' text1)` would split the output into individual tokens separated with whitespace and execute

```
levenshtein love love love
```

Comment: Good suggestion. It might be handy to explain the difference between process substitution and command substitution (Jorge's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use xargs also in case of multiple arguments

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387078/121634

Example

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces | grep Terminating |  awk 'NR>1 {print $1 " " $2}'  | xargs -n2  sh -c 'kubectl -
n $1 delete $2 --grace-period=0 --force' sh
```